# LinqtoSql using .first() with asp.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am using entity framework with the following linq query

```
 IQueryable<Order_Details> query = (from ord in ctx1.Order_Details
                             where ord.OrderID == 1
                             select ord).ToArray();

   gv1.DataSource = query;
   gv1.DataBind();
```

I get a result ok, return a row with orderId of 1
When I use the following,

```
var query = (from ord in ctx1.Order_Details
             where ord.OrderID == 1
            select ord).First() as IQueryable<Order_Details>;

gv1.DataSource = query;
gv1.DataBind();
```

I don't recive any results in the gridview

Comment: I am trying to learn ho to use the .First() exstension in a query. I want to get the same result with it as the origional code.  I tried to cast to IEnumerable<Order_Details>, and also null.  How can I get the same results as the origional code using .First()

Comment: First always returns 1 object, IQueryable always works with collections, so that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First() returns the Order_Detail record itself, not a collection/array, and therefore is not IQueryable; so using `as IQueryable<Order_Details>` will return null because it can't be cast.  Casting to IQueryable<> can only work for an enumerable of some sort.

If you have to use First, bind to the gridview like this:

```
var query = (from ord in ctx1.Order_Details
             where ord.OrderID == 1
            select ord).First();

gv1.DataSource = new[] { query };
gv1.DataBind();
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the same thing in C# but in VB you should be able to use .Take(1) in place of the .First() and it should return an enumerable collection. That way you can avoid copying it into a new collection.

Comment: @Adam Take(1) is the same in both, and it does get 1 record.  So yes, that would work too; other side effect of first; it expects at least one record... use FirstOrDefault() if it may be zero; it returns null when no record is found.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to cast a single `Order_Details` object to `IQueryable<Order_Details>`

Since that's not a valid cast, `null` is being returned, and your grid is not showing any results.

Your GridView is expecting an `IEnumerable`, so your original code was correct.  Why did you try to change it?